# SharePoint 2013 - List View Based on Selected Language

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-server, variations

I am currently building an intranet portal using SharePoint 2013. It is a bilingual site, and I have installed the language pack of the second language. I also have created a site collection using that second language as default language.

In the site content, I have added a list with columns like : title_id, title_en, content_id, content_en. Is it possible to create a view which show that specific column based on the selected language?

Answer (score 0):

When variation configured properly there should be a separate site for each language. When users visit the root site, they are redirected to the appropriate variation site, based on the language setting of their web browser.  So, it might not be a good idea to create columns like that unless it's a business requirement.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628966.aspx

Comment: Yes I have properly configured the variations (there are separate site for each language, the list item in target language updated when source is added / updated, etc).
Unfortunately, yes, it is a business requirement. Basically the client wants to manage the multilanguage site from 1 content source only (It will be more convenient for the client to manage 1 sites with lists in bilingual columns like title_id, title_en, rather than manage lists on 2 sites with variations). That's why I am curious if there is any way to filter list view based on the selected language..